# InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.RoleManager

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I got this error when I added a Createrole action to an Admin controller. Have seen similar questions but the only problem is that none of the solutions seem to work for me.

```
public class AdminController : Controller
    {
        private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;

        public AdminController(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
        {
            _roleManager = roleManager;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Authorize]
        public IActionResult CreateRole()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

My startup.cs file looks like this

```
       public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {


            //Server configuration 

            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddRoles<IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>(); 

            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(_configurationRoot.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Is there anything I could be missing

Comment: Is the error message in your title just a typo? i.e. It would be `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager` and not `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.RoleManager`. Unless that's the problem, because you're mixing ASP.NET 4.x and ASP.NET Core.

Comment: I don't believe its a typo, I just copied the error message which the browser shows

Comment: Well that would explain the error, then. The `RoleManager<IdentityRole>` that gets added by `AddIdentity` is for ASP.NET Core, but your controller appears to be asking for the `RoleManager<IdentityRole>` that's part of ASP.NET 4.x (not Core). It looks like you've added references to the older ASP.NET.

Comment: Thank you this seemed to be the problem

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

** `services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>().AddRoles<IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();` **

NameSpace detail

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity